# Aligning images side by side

Tags: html, css

How  to align the images side by side like css sprite

```
 <style>
.a, .mail-green, .star{ display: block; background: url('http://css.spritegen.com//uploads/ka3dublic7f3p1363fcj1lpei1.png') no-repeat; }
.a { background-position: -0px -0px; width: 103px; height: 30px; }
.mail-green { background-position: -0px -30px; width: 159px; height: 30px; }
.star { background-position: -0px -60px; width: 198px; height: 28px; }
</style>
<div class="a"/>
<div class="main-green"/>
<div class="star"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML isn't valid ...

```
<div class="a"/>
```

should be

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

and as `block` elements take up a single line they won't all appear next to each other .... you should consider using `inline-block` or perhaps `float`ing the `div` elements and applying a `width`

I have created an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/GCwaU/) using `inline-block` but am not really sure what your desired output is so it may be incorrect.

[Here are the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) for the `display` property, including its valid values. And [here is a good article on CSS Floats](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/)